# Concat two Pandas DataFrame column with different length of index

Tags: python, pandas

How do I add a merge columns of Pandas dataframe to another dataframe while the new columns of data has less rows? Specifically I need to new column of data to be filled with NaN at the first few rows in the merged DataFrame instead of the last few rows. Please refer to the picture. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
        'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
        'SMA':list('rty')
})

df3 = df1.join(df2.set_index(df1.index[-len(df2):]))
```

Or:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2.set_index(df1.index[-len(df2):])], axis=1)
print (df3)
   A  B  SMA
0  a  4  NaN
1  b  5  NaN
2  c  4  NaN
3  d  5    r
4  e  5    t
5  f  4    y
```

How it working:

First is selected index in `df1` by length of `df2` from back:

```
print (df1.index[-len(df2):])
RangeIndex(start=3, stop=6, step=1)
```

And then is overwrite existing values by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
print (df2.set_index(df1.index[-len(df2):]))
  SMA
3   r
4   t
5   y
```

Comment: The answer works. I have to do a df1.reset_index() first in my case.